# Spring boot multiple gradle projects dependcy mangament -> Cannot change dependencies of configuration

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, gradle-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have few projects each with structure something like that

```
projectA
| - projectA-module1
| - projectA-module2
| - projectA-service
```

project-service -> this module has applied spring boot plugin, it is deployable all other modules are dependencies for this module. Each module needs only specific spring dependencies for ex. module1 need mail api, module2 need only rabbitmq api etc. I wanted to void adding spring boot plugin with all of it dependencies to each of the modules. So I thought that I can use dependency-management-plugin and add to each moduleX and configure it and for module service just configure it because it will be already added by plugin spring boot. In my custom plugin I have this function to do this:

```
protected def addAndConfigureDependencyManagementExtension(){
    if(project.name.matches("[a-z]*-service")){
        LOGGER.info("Project ${project.name} have allready applied plugin ${SPRING_DEPENDENCY_PLUGIN_ID}. Just configure it")
        validateSpringBootVersions()
    }else {
        DependencyManagementPlugin dependencyManagementPlugin = new DependencyManagementPlugin()
        dependencyManagementPlugin.apply(project)
    }
    project.extensions.configure(DependencyManagementExtension, new ClosureBackedAction<DependencyManagementExtension>({
        imports {
            mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
        }
    }))
}
```

Here is my moduleX build.

```
apply plugin: 'myplugin'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web'
}
```

Here is build.gradle for my service module:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.2.RELEASE'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'my-plugin'

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-remote-shell')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile project(':my-project')
}
```

And the issue is that when I am trying to run ./gradlew build I am getting:

```
Cannot change dependencies of configuration 'detachedConfiguration1' after it has been resolved.
```

I don't know exactly why it is occurring and how to solve this. Thanks in advance for any suggestion, tips. Perhaps that are easier way | or already available solutions to achieve dependency consistency?

EDIT:
Here is stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change dependencies of configuration 'detachedConfiguration1' after it has been resolved.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.validateMutation(DefaultConfiguration.java:597)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$2.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.assertMutable(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:267)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:158)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.add(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:81)
    at java_util_Set$add$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagement$_resolve_closure2.doCall(DependencyManagement.groovy:150)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagement.resolve(DependencyManagement.groovy:150)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagement.resolveIfNecessary(DependencyManagement.groovy:130)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagement.getExclusions(DependencyManagement.groovy:124)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagement$getExclusions$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementContainer.getExclusions(DependencyManagementContainer.groovy:104)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementContainer$getExclusions$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction.findExcludedDependencies(ExclusionConfiguringAction.groovy:99)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction.applyMavenExclusions(ExclusionConfiguringAction.groovy:76)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction.this$2$applyMavenExclusions(ExclusionConfiguringAction.groovy)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction.execute(ExclusionConfiguringAction.groovy:71)
    at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction.execute(ExclusionConfiguringAction.groovy)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.beforeResolve(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.performPreResolveActions(DefaultConfiguration.java:384)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:365)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:342)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:335)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:661)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:288)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:186)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.visitFiles(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init>(TaskUpToDateState.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

EDIT 2

I have created two github projects to reproduce issue. Here are links
[project](https://github.com/lethalToxin/spring-boot-test-project.git) and [plugin](https://github.com/lethalToxin/gradle-example-plugin). What I noticed that on Intellij 15 refresh gradle project does not work because of "Error:Cannot change dependencies of configuration 'detachedConfiguration1' after it has been resolved." However gradle build from command line almost works. Only problem that exists in new setup is that configuring dependency management plugin from my plugin seems not to working. I need to repeat dependencyManagement in test-service/build.gradle. There is something wrong with the code?

Comment: What's the stacktrace of the failure? You can run with `--stacktrace` to get Gradle to show it to you.

Comment: The dependency management plugin uses a detached configuration to resolves any boms that have been imported. The failure you're seeing occurs when it tries to resolve that configuration but it's already been resolved. That shouldn't happen (the plugin keeps track of whether or not the configuration has already been resolved). I can't piece together why it's happening from your description. Can you please share all of the code and `build.grade` scripts that are necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: added links to github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your reproduction your plugin contains this logic:

```
@Override
void apply(Project project) {
    if(project.name.matches("[a-z]*-service")){
        println("Skipping dependency managament plugin for ${project.name}")
        return
    }else {
        println("Added dependency managament plugin for ${project.name}")
        DependencyManagementPlugin dependencyManagementPlugin = new DependencyManagementPlugin()
        dependencyManagementPlugin.apply(project)
    }
    project.extensions.configure(DependencyManagementExtension, new ClosureBackedAction<DependencyManagementExtension>({
        imports {
            mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
        }
    }))
}
```

And you said:

> Only problem that exists in new setup is that configuring dependency management plugin from my plugin seems not to working. I need to repeat dependencyManagement in test-service/build.gradle

This is due to the `return` statement in the first `if` block. Rather than just skipping the logic the applies the dependency management plugin, you're also skipping the logic that imports the Spring Cloud bom.

Without that `return` statement, your sample project builds successfully for me with `./gradlew clean build`.

Comment: of course You are right. After removing this return it works like a charm. Thanks a lot for quick help.